# How can I force a Yeoman generated Angular project's bower.json to use the .min.js version?

Tags: angularjs, bower, yeoman-generator-angular

I am currently working on a Yeoman generated Angular project.

I'd like to force bower.json to only utilize a dependency's *.min.js file rather than the full *.js version.  I'm sure this is relatively easy to configure but I can't seem to figure it out.

For example, the following is being automatically injected:

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-chart/angular-chart.js"></script>
```

Instead of:

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-chart/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
```

Here's the full HTML from the relevant section:

```
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-utils-pagination/dirPagination.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/spin.js/spin.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-spinner/angular-spinner.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/d3/d3.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/c3/c3.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-circular-navigation/angular-circular-navigation.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-chart/angular-chart.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciate.  Thank you!

Comment: Can you please post some fo your html is the script in the `<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->` section?

Comment: Sure thing, I've edited the question and posted it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that when you are running it for development you want to use the non minified js so that if there are any issues you can read the source easily. To run for development you would just use:

```
grunt serve
```

Then when you are ready to deploy it you can just run:

```
grunt
```

This will produce a minified combined `scripts/vendor.js`. The ful build solution will be in the `dist` folder.